# ingresar n valores con ArrayList y luego mostrarlos

Tags: java, array, arraylist

Hola estoy tratando de aprende java y quede estancada en esto. Resulta que quiero crear un ArrayList en el que vaya ingresando valores hasta ingresar un numero especifico y este se cierre. En teoría creo que logre hacer la primera parte que es ingresar n números aunque tampoco se si esta bien. Con do y while cree un bucle que al ingresar un numero especifico el programa se cierra.

```
    package arraylist;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class ArrayList {
   
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        
            int num=0;
            //inicio bucle ingreso n numeros
            do {
                Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in); 
                ArrayList<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                System.out.println("ingrese los numeros: ");

                num = entrada.nextInt();
                numeros.add(num);
            
            }while(num!=100);  // bucle termina
        }    

    }
```

en si si el código anterior esta bien me falta la manera de hacer para poder imprimir los números ingresados. Me pueden echar una mano porfavor

Answer (score 2):

Tienes varios errores en tu código, el más importante es el nombre de la clase, no puedes utilizar nunca palabras reservadas pra nombrar objetos, y ArrayList es palabra reservada.

Como bien dice @OsmairoCastillo, el arrayList lo tienes que declarar fuera del bucle

El objeto teclado de la clase scanner  mejor sacarlo también del bucle para evitar sobrecarga, con declararlo una vez es suficiente y no en cada iteración

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int num=0;
    ArrayList<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in); 
    
    //inicio bucle ingreso n numeros
    do {
        //mejor que no pongas ingrese números en plurar, pues en cada iteración te pedirá sólo un número hasta que pongas el 100, por lo que quedará mejor pedir de uno en uno
        System.out.println("ingrese un numero: (100 para finalizar)");
        //almacenamos el número introducido por teclado en la variable num
        num = entrada.nextInt();
        //agregamos el valor de la variable num al arraylist
        numeros.add(num);
        
    }while(num!=100);  // termina el bucle al introducir el número 100
    
    //con éste bucle recorres e imprimes los valores del arrayList
    for(Integer i: numeros){
        System.out.print(i, ", ");                 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

am Hola, veo el problema, el arrayList esta declarado esta dentro del bucle, eso hace que en cada vuelta se cree nuevamente siendo asi nunca guardar los datos los solucionas sacandolo del el ej:

```
  int num = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> numeros = new  ArrayList<Integer>();

//inicio bucle ingreso n numeros
    do {
        //resto del codigo
    } while (num != 100);  // bucle termina
```

Comment: Ya tienes una respuesta, si deseas añadir nuevas soluciones, edita tu primera pregunta por favor

Answer (score 0):

para mostrar los datos puedes usar un bucle for o bien la funcion forEach Ej:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numeros.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(numeros.get(i));
}
```